# xcode7 could not connect to the device

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I'm trying to test my app in my real device but when it says " finished running app on iPhone" then i get error message:

> Could not connect to the device.

here a picture: http://cut.by/XKX7P

How to fix that please?

Comment: Try reconnecting and trying again, restarting the phone, or restarting Xcode.

Comment: You tagged your question with both xcode6 and xcode7, does that mean you have that problem in both IDE versions? If not, please consider editing your original question.

Comment: What iOS version is your phone running? What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: @der_michael iphone : 7.1 , OS X : 10.10.5

Comment: @ILikeTau I restarted a lot it wont work

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @ILikeTau xcode 7 beta

Comment: Which beta? What's the beta number?